# Can I aggregate a fieldless array with known order in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Can I use the Aggregation framework for reformatting an array results set with 'unnamed' entries?

```
db.results.find();
{
  _id: '...',
  headers: ['date', 'field1', 'field2'],
  rows: [
  // Always in the same order as specified in headers above
     ['2014-01-01', 'some string', 5.1],
     ['2014-01-02', 'some string', 4.9],
     ['2014-01-03', 'yet a string', 1.2],
     ...
  ]
}
```

Can I transform this into a grouped, summarized result by one of the fields, even if it is not named in the actual `rows` array?

Desired outcome:

```
[
  { _id: '...', field1: 'some string',  field2: 10   },
  { _id: '...', field1: 'yet a string', field2: 1.2  }
]
```

Comment: Possible. Yes. But just not understanding your use case. Are you looking to somehow sum individually each `n` element of a given array across records? This could probably do with some explanation in your question.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks. I tried clarifying with what I really want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Mapping

---

Not really something that is possible for the aggregation pipeline right now, but it something you can do with mapReduce. First define a mapper:

```js
var mapper = function () {

  var headers = this.headers,
      newrows = [];


  this.rows.forEach(function(row) {
    var obj = { };
    for ( var i=0; i<row.length; i++ ) {
      obj[headers[i]] = row[i];
    }
    newrows.push(obj);
  });

  emit( this._id, newrows );

};
```

Then run the mapReduce:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
   mapper,
   function(){},
  { 
      "out": { "replace": "newcollection" }
  }
)
```

Which would output that result to "newcollection" and you could then run aggregate over that collection.

---

## Aggregating

---

So that was the first part. For something **small** you can modify this and keep this all within a mapReduce operation. Which is the best approach for smaller data sets since you already need to use mapReduce to get to this point.

**MapReduce**

```js
var mapper = function () {

  var headers = this.headers,
      newrows = [];

  this.rows.forEach(function(row) {
    var obj = { };
    for ( var i=0; i<row.length; i++ ) {
      obj[headers[i]] = row[i];
    }
    newrows.push(obj);
  });

  newrows.forEach(function(row) {
      emit(
          { _id: this._id, date: row.date, field1: row.field1 },
          row.field2
      );
  });
```

};

Or something a bit more flexible to what you want. But you can always generate the code.

Then you want a reducer in this case as there will be multiple "keys" emitted that are the same.

```js
var reducer = function( key, values ) {

    var reducedValue = 0;

    values.forEach(function(value) {
        reducedValue += value;
    });

    return reducedValue;
};
```

And then you can get the results from running the mapReduce:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
   mapper,
   reducer
  { 
      "out": { "inline": 1 }
  }
)
```

**Aggregate**

For larger result sets from the first introduced way of mapping, then aggregate is the better method to run over the resulting collection. Albeit a "two" step operation. So after using the **first** example of "mapReduce" operations then you can work on the new collection like this:

```js
db.newcollection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$value" },
    {"$group": { 
        "_id": { 
            "_id": "$_id",
            "date": "$value.date"
        }, 
        "field1": { "$first": "$value.field1"}, 
        "field2": { "$sum": "$value.field2" } 
    }}
])
```

Which again can be generated to suit your needs.

---

## Conclusion

---

So there are the examples to your approach. They may need some adjustment to fit your needs, but the general concepts are shown.

Also please note that in out *"conversation"* on this we clarified that the "date" component was integral to your "grouping". In your question sample the results are implied by just the `_id` value. So again depending on what you need, then only include the "grouping" fields that you require.

Comment: Hi Neil, thanks for your help. I think you're on the right path. This works flawlessly if I run it in say the Chrome console. But in MongoDB, my results look like this: `{_id: 'xyz', value: [{'[object Object]': value}, {...}, ...]}`. value is for some reason the value of the N-3:rd field of each row.

Comment: @DavidAndersson. Yeah the mapReduce output is pretty weird. But where are you running this? Console? with meteor? And the other backend thing. Meteor or plain node? JSON.stringify to get a nicer representation of the object. Which is what goes into the "value" field.

Comment: My purpose is for a Meteor app, but the result in my comment is from a Robomongo console. What I meant with my comment was that running on a plain JS object in the Chrome console yields the desired outcome, but in Mongo it does not. If this output is correct (it seems incorrect to me), how would I aggregate?

Comment: @DavidAndersson Sorry I completely missed that part of your question. There are a few approaches. What **exactly** do you want to aggregate by? I presume you want this consolidated by `_id` and the `date` summing the values for `field`. Is that correct?

Comment: @DavidAndersson I think those options are covered now. Hope that explains things.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time showing both approaches. I appreciate it!

Comment: @DavidAndersson not a problem. Hope it helps you and others as well. Upvote where this actually helps. It's appreciated :)